# Identifying linear and non-linear differential equations; eg, $5(1-y^2)\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+7y^2\frac{dy}{dt}+3y=e^t$ and $\frac{d^7y}{dt^7}+ty^8=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve some practice problems and I am not sure how to tell if a differential equation is linear or non linear.

The first problem: $$5\left(1-y^2\right)\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+7y^2\frac{dy}{dt}+3y=e^t$$
I think it is non Linear because $y^2$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ are multiplied, so it would make it non-linear. Could someone explain that to me?

The second was $$\frac{d^7y}{dt^7}+ty^8=0$$
I think it is linear. Could someone explain that to me?

Comment: Linear differential equations are of the form $a_n(t) \frac {d^ny}{dt} +   a_{n-1}(t) \frac {d^{n-1}y}{dt}+\cdots a_1(t) y = a_0(t)$   All the terms are derivatives of $y$ multiplied by  functions of $x$ or $t$ but not functions of y.  And, there is no exponentiation of the $y$'s or the derivatives of $y.$   They are both non-linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is correct, the presence of $y^2 y''(t)$ makes it non-linear. The second one is non-linear too, since $y$ appears to a power that is not $1$ or $0$, as you have $y^8$ term.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aryadeva points out, neither is linear.

A *linear ODE* is one of the form
$$p_0y+p_1y’+\cdots+p_ny^{(n)}=q$$
where the $p_k$ and $q$ are fixed functions of the independent variable.

The differential operator
$$P(D^0,D^1,\ldots,D^n)=\sum_{k=0}^np_kD^k$$
is linear since
$$\sum_{k=0}^np_kD^k\{ay_1+by_2\} =a \sum_{k=0}^np_kD^ky_1 + b \sum_{k=0}^np_kD^ky_2$$ and the ODE can be written as
$$P(D^0,\ldots,D^n)y = q.$$
It’s the linearity of the operator that makes the equation a linear ODE.

Comment: The second one is not linear. Due to the presence of $y^8$

Comment: @Aryadeva : Yes, of course, good grief. I should read more carefully, thanks. Correcting my answer. +1 for you.

Comment: You're welcome your answer is a nice one.